# Create shapes and put it inside the array list. (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

So I need to create about 10 shapes and put it in the array list shapes and then passes the list to the component.

I need a little bit of help and want to know if I'm on the right track.

So here's the code:

```
public class ShapeDemo
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 300 ;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 400 ;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>() ;
     Random random = new Random() ;
     int x, y ;
     // create the ten shapes and put them in shapes array list below.
     /*
        put code here

     */

     JComponent component = new ShapeComponent2(shapes) ;
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("") ;
     frame.add(component) ;
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
     frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT) ;
     frame.setVisible(true) ;
    }
}
```

What I was thinking of doing was for creating the shapes is:

```
shapes.add( new Ellipse.Double(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT));
```

Doing that with 10 times. But that doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
These are my imports:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame ;
import javax.swing.JComponent ;
import java.awt.Rectangle ;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D ; 
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D ;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D ;
import java.awt.Shape ;
import java.util.ArrayList ;
import java.util.Random ;
```

Comment: @Ferrybig its saying "variable x might not have been initialized" and "variable y might not have been initialized"

Comment: x and y don't have values yet so that's why you're getting that error. Where is x and y being initialized with their values?

Comment: If **that** is your issue, then **please** add this information to the question. Otherwise, please add your imports - what `Shape` class is that? JavaFX? There is no `Ellipse.Double` in JavaFX, and in Java2D its called `Ellipse2D.Double`

Comment: How would I make it so x and y does have values, and @AndreasFester I edit the post with the imports and yeah I just noticed that and fixed it.

Comment: Well are x and y supposed to have random values or are they always going to be the same for each shape?

Comment: @NiallMitch14  it suppose to have random values

Comment: I'll make an answer. Give me a minute or two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x and y are supposed to have random values for each shape, the best way to do what you are trying to accomplish will be with a for loop:

```
public class ShapeDemo
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 300 ;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 400 ;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>() ;
     Random random = new Random() ;
     int x, y ;
     // create the ten shapes and put them in shapes array list below.

     for (int i=1; i<=10;i++) {
         x = random.nextInt(100);// random number in range of 0-99. Can be changed if needed to suit
         y = random.nextInt(100);
         shapes.add( new Ellipse.Double(x,y,WIDTH,HEIGHT));
     }
     JComponent component = new ShapeComponent2(shapes) ;
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("") ;
     frame.add(component) ;
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
     frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT) ;
     frame.setVisible(true) ;
    }
}
```

The for loop will give integers x and y a random number each time and should add 10 new shapes to the ArrayList.

Comment: No problem :) Good to know that helped